# mainView shifts when adding tab bar controller from app delegate

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiwebview, uitabbarcontroller

I am creating a tab bar in the app delegate using the code below, but when I run the app everything in the view that I have setup in IB has been shifted down (using storyboards). Anyone have any suggestions?

```
//************ Add Tab Bar ***********************************
MainViewController *controller = (MainViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

self.tabController = [[SGTabsViewController alloc] init];
self.tabController.delegate = self;
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

[self.tabController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
[self.tabController.view setFrame:controller.view.bounds];
[self.tabController addViewController:controller];

double delayInSeconds = 0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self.tabController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
});
```

[image]

Comment: Is 'SGTabsViewController' setup in StoryBoard ?

Comment: no, it is not i'm calling it's functions from Appdelegate and from the MainViewController.